# Copy Exe file with batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a file on this path::

```
server\E:\ATSQL_17\accounts.exe
```

In a Batch file, I want to copy the above file to this path:

```
client1\desktop
```

I mean from server to workstation.

How to prepare to a batch file to do the job?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: may i ask why minus point? a

Comment: research `Xcopy` did you try any code prior to posting this?

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO ON
XCOPY "E:\ATSQL_17\accounts.exe" "client1\desktop\" /C /E /Y
PAUSE
```

Change the paths to whatever you got.

Also make sure you have enabled file sharing for the folder on the workstation.

Check out [this link](http://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) for details.